# VBscript for adodb query

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, adodb

I need to add a few lines to our billing system, and I don't know enough about the syntax of this call.  Can someone tell me what the zero's in the first line of this query means?

```
  strSqlStmt = strSqlStmt & "SELECT Trim(users.PILastName & ' ' & users.PIFirstName), 0, 0, 0, 0, Count(plab.billing), 0, 0, 0 " 
  strSqlStmt = strSqlStmt & "FROM plab, pform, users, userinfo "
  strSqlStmt = strSqlStmt & "WHERE userinfo.PI=users.PI "
  strSqlStmt = strSqlStmt & " AND UCase(users.location) ='S' "
  strSqlStmt = strSqlStmt & " AND plab.sampleid=pform.sampleid " 
  strSqlStmt = strSqlStmt & " AND plab.email=userinfo.email " 
  strSqlStmt = strSqlStmt & " AND plab.finisheddate Between " & dtmRange & " "
  strSqlStmt = strSqlStmt & " AND plab.finished=True "
  strSqlStmt = strSqlStmt & " AND plab.billing = 1 "
  strSqlStmt = strSqlStmt & "GROUP BY Trim(users.PILastName & ' ' & users.PIFirstName) "
```

Comment: Those are just constants that are going to be output as part of the query as column values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just static (constant) values `0` return in positions (columns) specified from `SELECT` statement

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b82a0/1)** example

Comment: +1 for the nice explanation and the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b82a0/1) example.